# About the classical mountain pass theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the classic mountain pass theorem

Mountain pass theorem: Let $X$ a Banach space and $\varphi \in C^{1}(X,R)$ a functional satisfying the Palais- Smale condition. If $e \in X$ and $0 < r < ||e||$ are such that

$$ a = max \{\varphi (0), \varphi (e) \} < \displaystyle\inf_{|| u|| = r} = b$$

then $c = \displaystyle\inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \displaystyle\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \varphi (\gamma(t))$ is a critical value of $\varphi$ and $c \geq b$. (Here $\Gamma = \{ \gamma \in C([0,1], X) ; \gamma (0) = 0 \ and \ \gamma(1) = e \}$

I am searching for a acccessible proof in the case a=b. (I only find in a paper a  very hard proof for a general case when the equality a=b occurs =) . Someone can say to me a reference?

thanks in advance

Comment: What paper have you found the proof?

Comment: this :  http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AIHPC_1989__6_5_321_0

Comment: Leandro, onde exatamente eles provam esse resultado com $a=b$?

Comment: Olá Tomás. Eu não li o artigo cuidadosamente, mas no livro clássico de Yousef Jabri (the mountain pass theorem) na página 99 eles dizem isso.

Comment: O caso $a=b$ se reduz a conhecer o caso $a\neq b$. Eu conheço dois tipos de demonstração do Teorema da Passo da Montanha: Uma usa Ekelenad e a outra usa Pseudo Gradiente. Ambas tem certo grau de dificuldade, mas a que eu acho mais fácil é a do Pseudo Gradiente.

Comment: Caso não seja incômodo , há como você me explicar essa redução?  Se for, há como você indicar uma referencia que tenha a redução ?

Comment: Na página 98 tem a solução. É o Teorema 9.5.

Comment: Olá Tomás. Então, só que eu gostaria que o ponto crítico fosse caracterizado conforme eu mencionei no enunciado de minha questão

Comment: Não estou entendendo. O ponto crítico é caracterizado da forma como você escreveu.

Comment: é que o Jabri comenta que o ponto crítico no teorema do Djairo e Solimmi (o teo que vc disse) não  é caracterizado como eu queria. vou ler a demonstração  do teorema deles

Comment: Can you please communicate in English so that interested people like me can follow what is a possible answer to a question?.